# One Embedded youtube video not playing, the other works

Tags: firefox, iframe, youtube, embedding, youtube-iframe-api

I have two youtube videos, which are both on my account, embedded in my website. The first one works fine, the second one gives me this message:
"Firefox Can’t Open This Page
To protect your security, [www.youtube.com](http://www.youtube.com) will not allow Firefox to display the page if another site has embedded it. To see this page, you need to open it in a new window."
I have clicked on more and as far as I understand its youtube blocking my video? How can I fix this please?
The website is [www.washbox-international.com](http://www.washbox-international.com)
Than you in advance - sorry am a novice!